# Is Dependency Injection A Standard in PHP and Laravel?

Tags: php, inversion-of-control, laravel, coding

Or in actuality, how to tell if a certain technique has became a standard in certain language / framework?

As I understood from my readings so far, PHP supports DI in PSR-11 while Laravel uses it out of the box...

But does this mean DI is a standard for PHP and Laravel or they just helped you to do it right, should you choose to use DI?

Comment: If you need DI, use DI. Otherwise, don’t.

Answer (score 2):

> Or in actuality, how to tell if a certain technique has became a standard in certain language / framework?

Closest thing to a standard in PHP is [PSR](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/). Apart from that, all frameworks, libraries and individual programmers have different approaches.

> As I understood from my readings so far, PHP supports DI in PSR-11 while Laravel uses it out of the box...

You have misunderstood. Dependency Injection is something that you as a programmer use to properly structure an application, that generally improves testability, readability and maintainability of your code. Any language that supports passing arguments to a function supports dependency injection.

Laravel... actually is generally the inverse of using dependency injection, even though they might advertise featuring a dependency injection *container*, that is used to instantiate your types. Laravel depends, as far as I know, on the global state for most actions, calls static functions from anywhere, which is the exact contrary of injecting dependencies into a class.